Is there a standard wall bracket, for these guys (perhaps a standard width?) or are they totally ad hoc depending on the device? The solid solution?
I have a number of these problem children to take care of. They should hang a foot above the floor on the wall.
My crap solution is push two small nails in to the drywall at an upwards angle and hang on those :/
(If you just use sticker or 3M -type pin hooks, small "picture hooks" it's crap, y ou need the right sort of knob-on-a-stick for it to snap in to unfortunately :/ )
Do these exist, standard thing or? Or do you just have to incredibly tediously buy the Official Wall Plate part from each and every manufacturer??  TY
it's not at all a weight issue (the units weigh less than a sandwich.) As I explained (sorry i must have done a poor job) in the question, it's useless using either screws or any of the many devices you can buy to hang pictures ("hooks" of various types). The fitting has to be exactly the "flat round knob on a stick" system that "clicks" in to these things with all dimensions exact and hence holds the whole thing snug and totally immobile. (If you use any sort of hook other than the designed-for=it device, the unit just bounds up and down and flops around!)

is that "knob fastener thing" a standard size?

is the width (images) standard?

are such standard plates available or ?





Drywall holds nails as much as you can push nails in by hand.  For light weight items that are not handled much, there are drywall anchors with screws.  They hold better than nails.  Even better is to put one screw into a stud and use one drywall anchor.

Hi @crip659, it's not at all a weight issue (the units weigh less than a sandwich.) As I explained (sorry i must have done a poor job) in the question, it's useless using either screws or any of the many devices you can buy to hang pictures ("hooks" of various types).  The fitting has to be **exactly the "flat round knob on a stick" system that "clicks" in to these things and holds the whole thing totally immobile.  (If you use any sort of hook other than the designed-for=it device, the unit just bounds up and down and flops around!)

Those openings you show are for screwheads to slip in.  The only fancy part is to get the two screws at the proper place.  Measure from the centre of both holes and leave the screw head out from the wall a bit and slip it on.

A special fitting is not required.
These are "keyhole" screw slots. The screw or nail head has to be wider than the narrow part of the slot but narrower than the wide part of the slot; the shaft has to be narrower than the narrow part. Install two fasteners at appropriate spacing. Drop the wide part of the slot over the screw, slide to trap the head behind the narrow part, done.
If you are worried about it bouncing free, you can adjust the strength of the attachment by how far the screw head rides above the surface and hence how strongly it pulls the slot against that surface. If you really need to secure it, mount it this way and then drive one more fastener to keep the slots from sliding back off the heads, though that is rarely needed.
Example from the back of a power strip I happened to have handy:


Wibble? Not if you tighten the screw down enough that it's a friction fit. And how often do you expect to physically disturb these? There may be conventional/named sizes, but I've never heard of them, and the packaging for such things doesn't mention them. Not everything needs to be overdesigned; good enough is usually good enough.

Some devices come with brackets so you can screw the bracket in place and then mount the device. That seems to usually be for style more than substance. My smoke detectors came with brackets, my carbon monoxide detectors didn't and slide into screws. Shrug.

Can't say there aren't, and I'm not sure there would be a market for them... I suspect it would be multiple spacings both English and Metric, and that there wouldn't be a lot of demand.  If one really insisted, someone with a 3D printer could probably generate something. But I really don't think it would be an improvement.
